# counting the total numbers of files and directories in a provided folder including subdirectories and their files

Tags: shell, sh

I want to count all the files and directories from a provided folder including files and directories in a subdirectory. I have written a script which will count accurately the number of files and directory but it does not handle the subdirectories any ideas ???
I want to do it without using **FIND** command

```
#!/bin/bash

givendir=$1
cd "$givendir" || exit

file=0
directories=0

for d in *;
do
 if [ -d "$d" ]; then
    directories=$((directories+1))
 else
    file=$((file+1))
 fi
done

echo "Number of directories :" $directories
echo "Number of file Files :" $file
```

Comment: oh and one more thing i want to do it without using find command.

Answer (score 1):

Use find:

```
echo "Number of directories:            $(find "$1" -type d | wc -l)"
echo "Number of files/symlinks/sockets: $(find "$1" ! -type d | wc -l)"
```

Using plain shell and recursion:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                               

countdir() {                                                                                              
  cd "$1"                                                                                                 
  dirs=1                                                                                                  
  files=0                                                                                                 

  for f in *                                                                                              
  do                                                                                                      
    if [[ -d $f ]]                                                                                        
    then                                                                                                  
      read subdirs subfiles <<< "$(countdir "$f")"                                                        
      (( dirs += subdirs, files += subfiles ))                                                            
    else                                                                                                  
      (( files++ ))                                                                                       
    fi                                                                                                    
  done                                                                                                    
  echo "$dirs $files"                                                                                     
}                                                                                                         

shopt -s dotglob nullglob                                                                                 
read dirs files <<< "$(countdir "$1")"                                                                    
echo "There are $dirs dirs and $files files"
```

Comment: @latitude8848: What kind of learning that will be? Using right tool for the right job is the best strategy to learn IMO.

Comment: I am a newbie in this section. I have already solved it using find command and it was not challenging enough. If i want to understand a programming language in detail then i will have find new ways for doing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`find "$1" -type f | wc -l` will give you the files, `find "$1" -type d | wc -l` the directories

My quick-and-dirty shellscript would read

```
#!/bin/bash

test -d  "$1" || exit
files=0

# Start with 1 to count the starting dir (as find does), else with 0
directories=1

function docount () {
    for d in $1/*; do
        if [ -d "$d" ]; then
                directories=$((directories+1))
            docount "$d";
        else
                files=$((files+1))
        fi
    done
}

docount "$1"
echo "Number of directories :" $directories
echo "Number of file Files :" $files
```

but mind it: On my build folder for a project, there were quite some differences:

- find: 6430 dirs, 74377 non-dirs
- my script: 6032 dirs, 71564 non-dirs
- @thatotherguy's script: 6794 dirs, 76862 non-dirs

I assume that has to do with the legions of links, hidden files etc., but I am too lazy to investigate: `find` is the tool of choice.

Comment: great script works fine.Outputs are similar to find command while i run it on my computer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here are some one-line commands that work without find:

**Number of directories:** `ls -Rl ./ | grep ":$" | wc -l`

**Number of files:** `ls -Rl ./ | grep "[0-9]:[0-9]" | wc -l`

Explanation:
`ls -Rl` lists all files and directories recursively, one line each.

`grep ":$"` finds just the results whose last character is ':'. These are all of the directory names.

`grep "[0-9]:[0-9]"` matches on the HH:MM part of the timestamp. The timestamp only shows up on file, not directories. If your timestamp format is different then you will need to pick a different grep.

`wc -l` counts the number of lines that matched from the grep.